# Why no dynamic debug messages shown from kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to print the dynamic debug messages produced by any modules. What I do is the same as the instruction stated in the kernel documentation on [dynamic debug](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.html). I do it for modules instead of files. I use the following command:

```
cut -f 2 -d "[" /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control | cut -f 1 -d "]" | xargs -i echo 'module {} +p' > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
```

The above instruction extracts the module names from control file and makes it to print the actual dynamic debug messages issued by `netdev_dbg()` for example.

I took this command from a paper on page 7 ([here is the link](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0edb/b6e2a4fdaf23c2affcfdd0d1345c3b00e2a3.pdf)) that explains dynamic debug and this example actually prints dynamic debug messages in their system. But in my system it does not print anything!

I have tested the first two `cut` commands extract the module names correctly but `xargs echo` command does not print the messages. I tried it on two different laptops.

I use `Ubuntu 16.04LTS`.

Comment: Dump the log with `dmesg`, and check if the debug messages show up there.  I.E. you probably have to change the log level.

Comment: Explain how you use that, what did you do after?

Comment: I did find the file to look into. It is `/var/log/syslog`. This file contains the messages I am looking for. The `dmesg` command would not show the messages for me for some reason. The file size is 7 GB! as I have enabled the messages for all modules.

Comment: Ah, that explains. Kernel's internal buffer is quite small, it can't fit 7Gb for sure.